# Explicit (Forward) and Implicit (Backward) Euler Methods in Python

Tags: python, jupyter, ode

I am trying to implement both the explicit and implicit Euler methods to approximate a solution for the following ODE:

***dx/dt = -kx***, where ***k = cos(2 pi t)***, and ***x(0) = 1***

Euler's methods use finite differencing to approximate a derivative:

***dx/dt = (x(t+dt) - x(t)) / dt***

The *forward* method explicitly calculates *x(t+dt)* based on a previous solution *x(t)*:

***x(t+dt) = x(t) + f(x,t)dt***

The *backwards* method is implicit, and finds the solution *x(t+dt)* by solving an equation involving the current state of the system *x(t)* and the later one *x(t+dt)*:

***x(t) = x(t+dt) - f(x,(t+dt))dt***

My code for approximating a solution to *dx/dt = -kx*, *x(0) = 1* and plotting it alongside the actual solution is given below:

```
### Import Necessary Packages
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'retina'
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10.0, 6.0)

### Defining Basic Data
t0 = 0                                # initial t
tf = 4*np.pi                          # final t       
N = 1000                              # factor affecting time step size
dt = (4*np.pi)/N                      # time step size (as a factor of N)
t = np.linspace(t0,tf,N)              # defining a vector of t values from t0 to tf  
x0 = 1                                # initial x
x = np.zeros([N])                     # initializing array for x values
f = lambda x,t: -np.cos(2*np.pi*t)*x  # defining f(x,t) on RHS on ODE

### Define a Function for Euler's Forward Method ###
def ForwardEuler(f,x0,t):
    x[0] = x0
    for i in range(1,N-1):
        x[i+1] = x[i] + (f(x[i],t[i]))*dt
    return x

# Plot Solution
forward = ForwardEuler(f,x0,t)
actual = 1/np.exp((1/(2*np.pi))*np.sin(2*np.pi*t))
plt.plot(t,actual,'r-',t,forward,'b-')
plt.legend(['Actual','Backward Euler'])
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.title("Solution to $x'=-kx$,   $x$(0)=1")
plt.grid(True);plt.show()
```

My question lies in how to adapt the for-loop section of the code to display the backward Euler method instead of forward Euler method. I am having trouble with this since the equations require you to know x[i+1] in order to solve x[i+1].

I believe the backwards for-loop would be what is given below, but I am unsure:

```
def BackwardEuler(f,x0,t):
    x[0] = x0
    for i in range(1,N-1):
        x[i] = x[i+1] - (f(x[i+1],t[i+1]))*dt
    return x
```

I have found very few resources online and am at a complete loss. Any help on this would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Your assumption that we know what the implicit or explicit euler methods are will li,it the number of respondents who will take the time to answer your question.  Please explain these terms in layman's vernacular.  Also, tell us what specifically is not working and why you believe it is incorrect.

Comment: @itprorh66 I tried to give a more detailed description regarding where I am stuck. Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: You need `t = np.linspace(t0,tf,N+1)` to get a sequence with the correct step size. N segments, N+1 points.

Comment: Is it demanded that you code this in a general way, or can you use that this equation is linear? Because then you can set `x[i+1]=(1+k(t[i])*dt)*x[i]` for the explicit method, and for the implicit one `x[i+1]=x[i]/(1-k(t[i+1])*dt)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, for Backward Euler and Trapezoidal Rule, you write the expression as a equation (or a system of equations), then **solve** it (i.e. **find its zeros**). The zeros represent the value of `x[i+1]`.

For example, for **Backward Euler**, the system is:

```
x[i+1] = x[i] + (f(x[i+1],t[i+1]))*dt
```

Which you can rewrite as:

```
x[i+1] - x[i] - dt*f(x[i+1], t[i+1]) = 0
```

The values `x[i]` and `t[i+1]` are known. The only unknown is `x[i+1]`. You can solve this system numerically (using something like `fsolve`), and the solution would be your `x[i+1]`. It is possible, of course, that you get more than one solution. You have to select the one that fits your problem (i.e. `x` cannot be an imaginary number, or `x` cannot be negative, etc.)

The same technique can be applied for **Trapezoidal Rule**, with the system being:

```
x[i+1] - x[i] - (f(x[i],t[i]) + f(x[i+1],t[i+1]))*(dt/2) = 0
```

**PS**: Check out [Computational Science StackExchange](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/). It is more suitable for question related to numerical and computational methods.

Answer (score 0):

In your for-loop you need the range to start at 0, otherwise you are missing x[0]:
for i in range[0,N-1]:

As a result I saw that in time the sinewave slowly goes down. This is what the 'actual' function does not do. It has to do with the size of td. If you make td smaller, the sinewave decends less and the error is less between 'actual' and 'forward'.